# how to inner join two datatable using diffrent database in MVC

Tags: database, model-view-controller, datatable

What is the best approach or code sample that can be used to inner join two datatable using different database using MVC

let say for Ex.

dt1 = "SELECT * FROM tbluser" - FROM database1

dt2 = "SELECT * FROM tblUserRole" = FROM Database 2

dt3 = Join d1.flduserid = d2.flduserID

Comment: Please share with us the database name, version, and programming language.  Is this VBA or C#?  And add these as TAG to your question instead of the too general "database"

Comment: Hi @donPablo, the language that im using is C#

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

```
SELECT d1.*,d2.* FROM  [DataBaseName].[dbo].tbluser d1 inner join [DataBaseName].[dbo].tblUserRole d2 on d1.flduserid = d2.flduserID
```

> Where

- [DataBaseName] - Your DB Name
- [dbo] - Your schema name(dbo is the default schema name)

Comment: Im asking for MVC not for database sir.